# VBA Looped MsgBox only appears once

Tags: xml, vba, excel, import

```vb
Function Schaltfläche1_Klicken()

Dim Zeile As Integer
Zeile = 0
Dim Node As String
Dim pfad As String

Set dlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    dlg.Title = "Bitte geben Sie den Pfad an"
    dlg.ButtonName = "Laden"
    dlg.Filters.Clear
    dlg.Filters.Add "XML", "*.xml"

If dlg.Show Then
     pfad = dlg.SelectedItems(1)
End If

If pfad = "" Then
    MsgBox "Sie haben keine Datei ausgewählt."
End If

Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    xmlDoc.SetProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
    xmlDoc.Async = False
    xmlDoc.Load (pfad)



While Zeile <> 100
    Zeile = Zeile + 1

    Node = Cells(Zeile, 1).Value
    Node = Replace(Node, ".", "/")

    If Node = "" Then
        Cells(Zeile, 2).Value = " "
    Else
        Set nodeXML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(Node)

        For i = 0 To nodeXML.Length - 1
            Cells(Zeile, i + 2).Value = nodeXML(i).Text

             If nodeXML(i).Text = "" Then
                MsgBox ("Keinen Wert in Node: " & Node & " (Zeile: " & Zeile & ") gefunden. " & nodeXML(i).Text)
              End If

            Next
    End If
Wend

End Function
```

Hello Community,

i wrote this simple Code to import **XML_Nodes** into an Excel sheet.

The Function should start everytime i click the Button `Schaltfläche1` then show a File Dialog, so that the User can "import" XML files.

The Function now proceeds to iterate through every Node he can find in the Sheet (`A-1` to `A-X`) and write it into the excel file.

The Code so far runs properly but:

I want the message ox to pop up when the Node is empty.
At the Moment it just pops up once.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: at first glance, if you have no error message, I don't see a reason why it would only display the msgbox one time if you have several empty `nodeXML(i).Text`. Your code looks correct

Comment: I see many undeclared variables and errors in variable names, such as `Dim pfas As String` and then you use `pfad = ..`. I suggest you turn on "Tools, Options, Require variable Declaration".

Comment: @PaulOgilvie i turned on the option and declared all variables/ fixed the typo in pfad. It doesnt affect the Error Msg though.

Comment: Step through the code and check every `nodeXML(i).Text`. It may just be that there are no errors, i.e. no `nodeXML(i).Text = ""`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie There are Errors, i forced them by using some gibberish nodes and emptying some nodes in the XML, sadly i can't show the XML or the Excel Sheet since they contain internal Data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't there a difference between nodeXML is empty (length = 0) or a sub-node is empty (`nodeXML(i).Text = ""`)? So may be check both:

```
While Zeile <> 100
    Zeile = Zeile + 1

    Node = Cells(Zeile, 1).Value
    Node = Replace(Node, ".", "/")

    If Node = "" Then
        Cells(Zeile, 2).Value = " "
    Else
        Set nodeXML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(Node)
        If (nodeXML.Length = 0) Then
            MsgBox ("Keinen Wert in Node: " & Node & " (Zeile: " & Zeile & ") gefunden. ")
        Else    
            For i = 0 To nodeXML.Length - 1
                If nodeXML(i).Text = "" Then
                    MsgBox ("Keinen Wert in Node(" & i &"): " & Node & " (Zeile: " & Zeile & ") gefunden. " & nodeXML(i).Text)
                Else
                    Cells(Zeile, i + 2).Value = nodeXML(i).Text
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    End If
Wend
```

Comment: P.s.: the Rules of Defensive Programming require you to write `While Zeile < 100`

Comment: Yes your right, thats not needed for this app, but maybe its helpful for other people. You should add +1 to i in the Error Message since nodeXML.Length iterates at 1 and i at 0.

Comment: I don't get what you mean with +1. The for loop iterates from 0 and the XML nodes also. I took the loop from your original code.

Comment: Yes, but if i would run this Code now the Message would display: Keinen Wert in Node(0): " Node(Zeile: X ) gefunden. But actually the first Node is empty since Node.Length = 0 means the node doesnt exist

Comment: if `Node.Length = 0` then the for loop will not be executed because it is in the else part of your `If (nodeXML.Length = 0)`, hence the length is not zero. Although the _length_ can zero, the valid _indexes_ still start at zero. So a length of 1 will have `nodeXML(0)`.

Comment: Technical you are right, but i think it would confuse the user, since you would call the 0 Node first Node

Comment: That is a good reason. Programmers think of `array[0]` as the first element (square brackets from C) and of the range of valid indexes of an array of size _n_ as 0.._n-1_.

Comment: Yes i know that, but i had a similar thing sometime before asking this and the user was like wtf is Kunde0 (Customer0) ... finally i want to thank you alot for your positive feedback and the help with my question, cya soon

Answer (score 0):

```
Function Schaltfläche1_Klicken()

Dim Zeile As Integer
Zeile = 0
Dim Node As String
Dim pfad As String

Set dlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    dlg.Title = "Bitte geben Sie den Pfad an"
    dlg.ButtonName = "Laden"
    dlg.Filters.Clear
    dlg.Filters.Add "XML", "*.xml"

If dlg.Show Then
     pfad = dlg.SelectedItems(1)
End If

If pfad = "" Then
    MsgBox "Sie haben keine Datei ausgewählt."
End If

Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    xmlDoc.SetProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
    xmlDoc.Async = False
    xmlDoc.Load (pfad)



While Zeile <> 100
    Zeile = Zeile + 1

    Node = Cells(Zeile, 1).Value
    Node = Replace(Node, ".", "/")

    If Node = "" Then
        Cells(Zeile, 2).Value = " "
    Else
        Set nodeXML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(Node)
        If (nodeXML.Length = 0) Then
            MsgBox ("Keinen Wert in Node: " & Node & " (Zeile: " & Zeile & ") gefunden. ")

        End If

        For i = 0 To nodeXML.Length - 1
            Cells(Zeile, i + 2).Value = nodeXML(i).Text


        Next
    End If
Wend

End Function
```

Silly me, the error was, that nodeXML.Length returned 0 when the Node was empty, so the For Loop wouldn't run, i reworked the code, so it works and I hope you forgive my Dumbness.

Comment: Indeed...step through the code in the debugger... :-)

Comment: Isn't there a difference between `nodeXML` is empty (length = 0) or a sub-node is empty (`nodeXML(i).Text = ""`? So may be check both?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie i did but i'm new to vba so the debugger first looked like dark magic but i figured it out. Yes there is a difference, but we can ignore it atleast for this app, since the user only cares about fully empty nodes.